# How to get word/content from second set of quotes?

Tags: php, expression, quotes

I have a loop that is returning strings that look like the following...

- s:20:"D111 Free Delivery**";s:4:"0.00"
- s:32:"D111 3/5 day delivery service***";s:4:"6.99"
- s:32:"D111 2/3 day delivery service***";s:4:"8.99"

I have the regular expression to get the content from the first set of quotes.

`$shipping_name = preg_match('/"(.+?)"/', $shipp_option, $matches);`

But I also want to get the number inside the second set of quotes, how would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: is it serialize string ?

Answer (score 3):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the strings on the `;` delimiter, then [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) them:

```
$string = 's:20:"D111 Free Delivery**";s:4:"0.00"';
$array = explode( ';', $string);
list( $str, $number) = array_map( 'unserialize', $array);
echo $str . ' ' . $number;
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/PdntMF), which for your three test cases, outputs:

```
D111 Free Delivery**
0.00
D111 3/5 day delivery service***
6.99
D111 2/3 day delivery service***
8.99
```

*Edited to show how to capture each field in its own variable.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need two different variables. One with the wording and another with the number

Comment: That's a pretty simple modification - You sure you can't figure that one out on your own?

Comment: Sorry, I was being dense. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Explode!!!!

```
//inside your loop
    $halves = explode(';', $shipp_option);
    $first_half = explode(':', $halves[0]);
    $second_half = explode(':', $halves[1]);
    $shipping_name = trim($first_half[2], '"');//eg. D111 Free Delivery**
    $shipping_price = trim($second_half[2], '"');//eg. 0.00
//end inside your loop
```

OR...a bit faster:

```
//inside your loop
    $shipp_arr = explode(';:', $shipp_option);
    $shipping_name = trim($shipp_arr[2], '"');//eg. D111 Free Delivery**
    $shipping_price = trim($shipp_arr[5], '"');//eg. 0.00
//end inside your loop
```